# How to get current transaction from the dbcontext

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework 6, under the DbContext class you can get to current transaction by context.Database.CurrentTransaction. However this API doesn't seem like available in EF.Core. How can I retrieve current transaction object from a dbcontext in EF.Core?

Comment: I can't check the older versions, but in EF Core v1.1.0 you can use the same code as in EF6.

Comment: Can you point me to .Core documentation where DbContext has these properties available? I don't see these.

Comment: Sure, here you go https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_CurrentTransaction

Comment: That's beautiful. I am using EntityFramworkCore.Tools version 1.0.0preview2-final. Guess it was not in there. How can I know which version of documentation is it?

Comment: BTW your comments answer my question. You need to add it as answer so that I can mark it so.

Comment: Documentation is a tricky topic these days - it either lacks, or isn't up-to-date, not to say what is available since what version :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EF Core still lacks many EF6 features, but (slowly) is catching up.

In that regard, I can't say for earlier versions, but in the latest (so far ) v1.1.0 the `DbContext.Database` [`CurrentTransaction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_CurrentTransaction) property is there, so you can use the same code as in EF6 to access it.